# Delete character " from a string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete the `"` character from my string. But I don't succeed. I'm doing :

```
char[] liste = { '\"' };
response = response.Trim(liste);
```

or:

```
response = response.Trim('\"');
```

But it does not succeed. I have another question. I would like to replace for example in this string:

```
 "token" : "scsdsd,vkf,vfk,"
```

Delete just the `"` that wraps the token. I don't know if it's possible or if I have to do my own parser. Thanks

Comment: `Trim` will only remove characters from  the beginning and ending of the string. Consider to replace it with `.Replace("\"", "");`

Comment: Please move your second question to a different, independent question. SO works best for single-question posts, so each can get the attention it needs.

Comment: To the second question, consider Split(':') and later combine the parts again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [`string.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method in order to replace all occurrences of a given string with another:

```
reponse = reponse.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] list = { '\"' };
            string response = "\"bla\"";
            response = response.Trim(list);

            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

" were trimmed. Of course, trimming works at the beginning and the end of strings. If you want to remove all " from the string, then you can use `Replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know if it doesn't work

```
var str = '\"';
str = new string((from c in str
      where char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)
      select c
   ).ToArray());
```